# Plotting points in x y frame

Tags: ros, rxplot, turtlesim, plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to plot the position of an object in a x-y 2D field.
Every time step the new position has to be added so you can see the path, similar to the turtle walking around in turtlesim.

I tried using rxplot, but this inserts an extra dimension for the time, and I want to have a 2D plane.

Has anyone a suggestion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46745/plotting-points-in-x-y-frame/) by [noe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3464/noe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can publish a LINE_LIST [visualization_msgs/Marker](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/Marker.html) to rviz.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-25**:
[relevant tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Points%20and%20Lines)